# A question about complete Noetherian local $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}_p[[X_{1},\cdots,X_{r}]]/(f_{1},\cdots,f_{s})$ be a complete Noetherian local $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers. Suppose that the quotient ring $A/(p)$ is finite. **Is it true that $A$ is a finitely generated module over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?**
I know that it is true if $r\geq s$. What about $r<s$? By [Lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031D), it suffices to show that $A$ is separated for the $p$-adic topology.